# Deployment error: injecting Spring bean in JSF ApplicationScoped bean with eager=true gives error in glassfish

Tags: spring, jsf, deployment, glassfish, glassfish-3

I want to inject spring bean as ManagedProperty in the jsf bean which is in Application Scope and also eagerly loaded.

```
@ManagedBean(name="SysProps", eager=true)
@ApplicationScoped
public class SysProps {     // jsf bean

   @ManagedProperty(value = "#{systemConfigService}")
   private SystemConfigService systemConfigService;    // spring bean
}
```

I want to load SysProps bean at deploy time and call one of its method which uses this spring bean. But it gives error while deploying in glassfish 3.1.2. The exception is,

```
com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: Unable to set property systemConfigService for managed bean sysProps
```

**This works fine in Jetty8 but same thing gives error in Glassfish 3.1.2.** That is because in glassfish, the jsf application scoped beans with eager attribute true, are loaded before spring beans are initialized so, it gives error while injecting spring beans. But same is not the case in Jetty8 and thus, works fine in it.

Can anyone provide me some alternate or good solution to load application scoped jsf bean eagerly (at deploy time) in which I should be able to inject spring beans also?